# Why is my react redux saga application crashing after removing immutableJs from it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

**The problem**

This is a very hard and weird problem because it's also very hard to explain.
I start from the beginning:

I started a new application using this boilerplate:

https://github.com/flexdinesh/react-redux-boilerplate

Everything worked fine until the owner of the repo made some small changes (look at the latest commit "Add prettier config; Upgrade deps; Remove immutable").

Since I don't like immutable I thought it would be great to also remove it. So I went into this projects commit and did exactly the same as he did. I also installed the same dep's versions as in his `package.json`.

Now the app is starting and when I load the page I see just a blank page with some errors in the devtools.

The errors can be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UahOb.jpg

One "bigger" change he also did is moving from `react-router-redux` to `connected-react-router`.

Also in the `injectReducer` and `injectSaga` files under `app/utils` he made some changes mainly importing `ReactReduxContext`. 
I'm specifically mentioning this because I think it has something to do with these changes.

**What have I tried**

I throw in some `debugger` statements in specific files and found out following:

- `injectReducer` file runs and gets the correct props
- `injectSaga` file doesn't run at all, I think because it's crashing before it get's executed. But I can't find out where and why.

I know this is hard to solve because it's a very big boilerplate code but you are my last hope (I already created an issue here: https://github.com/flexdinesh/react-redux-boilerplate/issues/38).

**Maybe one of you that has way more experience can find out what the problem might be (maybe from the differences between last version of this repo and the current commit, or the error messages).**

I really don't have much more "specific to the problem" code to give, since it could be really anything.

**If anyone wants to help me out here is the current repo with the same structure as this boilerplate, but with my own code:** https://github.com/SelfDevTV/forum-creator/tree/noImmutable

The `master` branch is working, that was before I "migrated" to the new version without immmutable and the other changes. 
The `noImmutable` branch is the "problem child".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my god that  feels so great.
I just diffed my repo with the boilerplate repo like this:

```
git remote add -f b path/to/repo_b.git
git remote update
git diff noImmutable:app/utils remotes/b/master:app/utils
git remote rm b
```

And I found out I made a single letter typo in the `injectSaga.js` file.

I typed: `static contextTypes = ReactReduxContext` instead of `static contextType = ReactReduxContext` (so an 's' too much :D)

After I fixed that everything is back to normal and works perfectly. 
Man moments like this are why I love coding and Git <3